# InfoWindow Google Maps Api, se muestra automáticamente

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Quiero que una `InfoWindow` se muestra automáticamente al entrar al sitio web, la verdad soy algo nuevo trabajando con la api de ***google***. Ya todo lo demás me funciona, solo necesito eso. espero me puedan ayudar, Dejo Código.

```
    <script>

var customIcons = { 
      Publico: { 
        icon: 'images/pin-location-mobo.png', 
      }, 
      Privado: { 
        icon: 'images/pin-location-mobo.png', 
      } 
    }; 

    function initMap() { 
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), { 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat . "," . $lng ?>), 
        zoom: 15,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
      }); 
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; 





      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
      downloadUrl("xmltiendas.xml", function(data) { 
        var xml = data.responseXML; 
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name"); 
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address"); 
          var horario = markers[i].getAttribute("horario");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type"); 
          var telefono = markers[i].getAttribute("telefono");
          var lada = markers[i].getAttribute("lada");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), 
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))); 
          var html = "<div class='infoWindow'><p class='title'>Cell Repair " + name + "</p> <p>" + address + "</p><p>" + "Teléfono: " + lada + " " + telefono + "<p/><p/>" + horario + "<p></div>"; 

          var icon = customIcons[type] || {}; 
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            map: map, 
            position: point, 
            icon: 'images/pin-location-mobo.png'
          }); 
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html); 

        } 
      }); 
    } 



  function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infoWindow.setContent(html); 
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
      }); 

    } 

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
          new XMLHttpRequest; 

      request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (request.readyState == 4) { 
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
          callback(request, request.status); 
        } 
      }; 

      request.open('GET', url, true); 
      request.send(null);




    function doNothing() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente se muestra en el `onclick` del marker:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```

Si quieres que se muestre siempre añade fuera del `onclick`:

```
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

En tu caso vendría a ser algo así:

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infoWindow.setContent(html); 
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
      }); 
      infoWindow.setContent(html); 
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    }
```

Espero que te funcione.

Comment: Hola, Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero ya lo he intentado así y se me desaparece el marker, la verdad ya no se porqué podría ser.

Comment: En tu caso tendrías que hacerlo en teoría con el modo de infowindow que has usado. Edito la respuesta a ver si te funciona.

Comment: Hola Muchas gracias Carmen, si me funciono algo, ahora el problema es que el mapa no me sale centrado y solo se va a una ubicación, si te fijas tengo diversas ubicaciones, que genero de un archivo xml,osea que en todos los infowindow me sale la misma información :( pero bueno gracias a la solución que me brindaste, estoy mas cerca, muchas gracias.

Comment: Al hacer el for no almacenes con el mismo nombre las variables que le pasas a bindInfoWindow para que no las sobreescriba, porque imagino que sólo te enseña la última.

Comment: Es correcto, bueno solamente me muestra la primera ubicación de todas las que tengo, entonces quieres decir que declare con otro nombre estas variables? marker, map, infoWindow, html, vas a decir que estoy muy verde XD, muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: map es único, pero se me ocurre que al menos infoWindow y su marker deberían ser diferentes, sino estás sobreescribiendo la misma variable.